# Dataframe : each column in different plot in subplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a panda Dataframe which I want each column to be represented on each subplot( 2 dimensions)

i know the default subplot of pandas is the desired output but 1 dimensional:

```
pallet       45   46   47   48   49   50
date
2019-04-15  4.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  2.0
2019-04-16  3.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
2019-04-17  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
2019-04-18  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
2019-04-19  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
2019-04-20  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

```
pivot.plot(subplots=True)
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

I want to be able to output each column but in 2-dimensional subplots.
**with common X and Y**
the columns length is **dynamic** so i want to be able to put like 6 columns on each figure, if num pallets > 6 open a new same-shaped figure.

so I want it to look like that:

[image]

but **with common X and Y**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can specify the [`layout`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#using-layout-and-targeting-multiple-axes) arg in `the .plot` method. For example:

*To generate subplots of 2 rows and 3 columns.*

```
pivot.plot(subplots=True, layout=(2, 3))
```

*To generate subplots over 2 rows, with columns being dynamically calculated.*

```
pivot.plot(subplots=True, layout=(2, -1))
```

*And if you need the subplots to share axis, you can pass `sharex` or `sharey`*

```
pivot.plot(subplots=True, layout=(2, -1), sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Amazing. you helped me alot to figure this one out! just, whata bout the open new figure for max num of cols?

Comment: you could use `layout=(-1, 6)` for example, if you wanted maximum 6 columns

Comment: I think i wasnt clear, i want to show all the pallets that i have information on. with the layout above. but if there are like 10 columns i want to be able to open a new window with  the rest f the columns, but in the same 2*3 layout (as you shows above) thanks again my friend

Comment: btw can you explain why the -1 makes it dynamic?

Comment: It is just a clever convention built into `pandas`, - similar to `numpy.reshape` - here are the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#using-layout-and-targeting-multiple-axes

Comment: Thanks, can you please try to help with the previous comment?

Comment: Not sure I understand the exact problem you have with regards to opening a new figure..?

Comment: if i have a six columns in the dataframe, the layout will be as above. if i have 12 columns i want python to open a new window with same figure layout . like to do figure() for each slice of 6 columns of the dataframe. whats the best way to do it?